# how to get the right url of file uploded to a local folder from localhost on Mac OS

Tags: php, apache

I have apache+PHP+mySQL  on the local Mac OS

and I just uploaded a file to the localpath folder, this is in uploaded.php and I just echo back the path so that the original php file can use it

```
 $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ;
 echo '{"url":"'.$targetPath.'"}';
```

But it turns out what's in the `url` is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, not what I have expected it as something like `http://localhost/~username/`, because this is the url of a picture, I need to retrieve it using in the `src`, I did not how to do it.

for example:
I just upload a file called 7.jpg, and what echo back is

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/7.jpg
```

but I need something like  `http://localhost/~username/7.jpg`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetPath = 'http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Here's why:

- `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` will output 'localhost' (or example.com, etc)
- `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` will output '/~username' (or /path/to/current/file)

See the PHP [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable for more info.

Comment: yeah, but this url is the full url of uploaded.php, how to get the parent directory of it?